# Nested Nested Comparator Classes

Tags: java, comparator, inner-classes

I'm having a hard time getting this to compile and can't quite figure out why. It looks like I'm messing something up with the nested classes. For some reason the ByManhattan class does not have access to Node? If someone could explain why that is along with what the error message means and offer a suggestion, that would be helpful. Thanks.

```
public class Solver {

  private class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    private Board board;
    private Node previous;
    private int moves;
    private int manhattan;
    private int priority;

    Node(Board b, Node p) {
        board = b;
        previous = p;
        if (previous == null)
            moves = 0;
        else
            moves = previous.moves + 1;
        manhattan = board.manhattan();
        priority = moves + manhattan;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node that) {
        return this.priority - that.priority;
    }

    // Why Doesn't this work???
    public Comparator<Node> manhattanOrder() {
        Comparator<Node> m = new ByManhattan();
        return m;
    }

    private class ByManhattan implements Comparator<Node> {
        public int compare(Node this, Node that) { // this is line 37
            return this.manhattan- that.manhattan;
        }
    }
  }

 MinPQ<Node> pq;
 ArrayList<Node> solution;

 // find a solution to the initial board (using the A* algorithm)
 public Solver(Board initial) {
 .
 .
 .
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Solver.java:37: error: the receiver type does not match the enclosing class type
public int compare(Node this, Node that) {
                   ^
required: Solver.Node.ByManhattan
found: Solver.Node
```

Comment: `this` is a reserved word. Bad practice to name a parameter after a reserved word, You should name it something different. Change the first parameter for `int compare(Node,Node)`

Comment: not 100% but try making the node class static.

Comment: ahhh! Thank you and sorry for the complicated question to a simple solution. Just changing the "this" worked. Can the question be removed?

Comment: Great im going to turn my comment into an answer. If that solved your problem please don't hesitate to give me the check mark :)

Comment: I think it's useful to keep this question, because of a Java 8 change that makes it legal to use an explicit `this` as the first parameter (so that you can put annotations on it).  Because of this, the error message would be very different (and less understandable) than previous versions of Java (although I haven't tried it).  So if anyone makes a similar mistake, Googles for that error message, and finds this question, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your parameter name :

```
   public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) { // this is line 37
        return n1.manhattan- n2.manhattan;
    }
```

Don't use the reserved word `this` for variables, that is a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reserved word. That is the source of your compilation error. It's also bad practice to name any parameter/variable after a reserved word, You should name it something different. Change the first parameter for int `compare(Node,Node)`